# Jenkins build after Eclipse commit on SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, build, jenkins, commit

I'm using **Jenkins** for **CI**, I'm trying to establish a build strategy. My point here is to **build**

after every **commit**. I saw that I need to create **post-commit** file in the **hooks** directory of my

project repository.

The porblem is that I'm using **SVN** as an **Eclipse** plugin, so I don't really have a repository,

I'm just using "right click -> Team " on my project to synchronize/update/commit ...

I can't see where to create my **post-commit** file in order to launch a **Jenkins** **build**.

Does anyone kow how to deal with this issue ?

I've seen many posts before, but none of them was helpful !

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use *Poll SCM* in your Jenkins job and have it look for changes e.g. every 5 minutes. It won't trigger the build instantly on commit, but it will decouple your SVN and Jenkins a bit more.

Comment: Actually the best practice is to use post-commit. I know that _Poll SCM_ is the simplest solution, but I wanna make sure that the way I want to do it is not possible before using _Poll SCM_. Are you usin _Poll SCM_ or post_commit file ?

Comment: I normally use Poll SCM, but using the Subversion Plugin you should be able to configure a commit hook, see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin - however this requires access to the subversion server (it is not a client side hook)

Comment: Then "Repository root" from svn info (or Subversion properties on your project) will point you to your local repository. Here there should be a folder called hooks.

Comment: There is no folder called hooks in the project Repository. Should I create one ?

Comment: Unless you are seeing the folders/files: conf  db  format  hooks  locks README.txt I am not sure you are looking the correct place.

Comment: MyProject -> Properties -> Info SVN -> Ressource URL = "http://svn..." Here I see my project tree but no hooks folder

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51275/discussion-between-michael-legart-and-ismail-sen)

Comment: Sorry but it's impossible for me due to Web Access Restriction in my office.

Comment: You are looking for the Repository Root, e.g:
$ svnadmin create /tmp/svnrepos
$ svn co file:///tmp/svnrepos checkout 
Checked out revision 0.
$ svn info checkout/ |grep Root 
Working Copy Root Path: /home/mil/checkout 
Repository Root: file:///tmp/svnrepos
$ ls /tmp/svnrepos/ 
conf db format hooks locks README.txt

Comment: Finally , I've choosen a poll every hour ( H * * * * ). If there is an update in the repo ( commit/add/...) it runs a build, if not, not build is programmed.